# How do I get editText information in Uri.Builder

Tags: android, android-edittext, uri, builder

I am building an app to upload Images to my company server 
The Upload URL must be created with a client ID(4 DIgits) an email and a password entered into editexts in a activity(LoginActivity) and that data is passed to another activivity(CameraActivity)
I am using URI.Builder to create the needed URL and I am stuck with two things I don't know if my edittext data(in a java LoginActivity) is being passed to the other activity(CameraActivity), And How Do I call the edit text data in URI.Builder

I have a basic understanding of how to build the needed URL statically by entering the needed info into `appendPath` and `ApppendQueryParamater` in URI.Builder so that will not be an issue 
I just need to Know how to call data from an `edittext` into appendQuEryParrameter etc.

**My URI Builder**

```
 private void uploadImageToServer() {
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("https")
            .authority("www.smartpractice.co.za")
            .appendPath("files-upload-ruben.asp")
            .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes");
           myURL =  builder.build().toString();

    File imageFile = persistImage(bitmap, "SP_Upload");
    Ion.with(this)
            .load(myURL)
            .setMultipartFile("SP-LOG", "image/jpeg", imageFile)
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {

                }
            });
```

**Login Activity passing edit text data to CameraActivity Here**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email, password, id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email=findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
        password=findViewById(R.id.pwdtext);
        id=findViewById(R.id.clientid);
        Button loginBtn=findViewById(R.id.button);

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailAddress=email.getText().toString().trim();
                String userPassword=password.getText().toString().trim();
                String clientId=id.getText().toString().trim();
                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("clientId", clientId);
                intent.putExtra("email", emailAddress);
                intent.putExtra("password", userPassword);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? get the params from the Login activity with `getintent().getextras()` using "clientId" and "email" as keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
uploadImageToServer(intent.getStringExtra("clientId"), intent.getStringExtra("email"),intent.getStringExtra("password"));
```

2.
If you need Uri like https://www.smartpractice.co.za/files-upload-ruben.asp?client_id=1234&email=example@gmail.com&pass=qwerty, so you can use code:

```
private void uploadImageToServer(String clientId, String email, String pass) {
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("https")
            .authority("www.smartpractice.co.za")
            .appendPath("files-upload-ruben.asp")
            .appendQueryParameter("client_id", clientId);
            .appendQueryParameter("email", email);
            .appendQueryParameter("pass", pass);
    myURL =  builder.build().toString();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Code above you provided is only one sided. Means you have provided intent of LoginActivity.

The code on other Side(**Camera Activity**) :

First, get the intent which has started your activity using the `getIntent()` method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Then retrieve all the data from Intent :

```
String clientid = intent.getStringExtra("clientId");
String emailAddress = intent.getStringExtra("email");
String userPassword = intent.getStringExtra("password");
```

Then pass it to the `uploadImageToServer`

Don't know how you called but pass them from Parameter

```
private void uploadImageToServer(String clientid, String emailAddress, String userPassword) {
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("https")
            .authority("www.smartpractice.co.za")
            .appendPath("files-upload-ruben.asp")
            .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes");   
            .appendQueryParameter("client_id", clientId);
            .appendQueryParameter("email", email);
            .appendQueryParameter("pass", pass);
           myURL =  builder.build().toString();

    File imageFile = persistImage(bitmap, "SP_Upload");
    Ion.with(this)
            .load(myURL)
            .setMultipartFile("SP-LOG", "image/jpeg", imageFile)
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {

                }
            });
}
```

I don't know which data you need for your uri.builder just make modification according your requirement.

When you pass through parameter you can access that data anywhere. In your function.